# ANTLR 4 - How to reduce prediction time for IF statements with optional END-IF (COBOL grammar)

Tags: performance, parsing, if-statement, antlr4, cobol

I've been working on a COBOL grammar and found that the generated parser runs very slow for programs having deeply nested IF statements.

I think it's better to look at a sample code first, to explain one of COBOL's "annoying" feature - one DOT (full stop) can close any level of unclosed nested IF statements. Here it is:

```
IF condition-1
    S1
    IF condition-2
        S2
        (more nested IF conditions)
           IF condition-n
               Sn
  (0~n "END-IF"s )
.
```

The text between parenthesis are pseudo code. The key point is that the "END-IF"s are optional before a DOT which closes a so-called "sentence" in COBOL. To allow the "END-IF"s to be optional, I've written the grammar this way:

```
sentence:
  statement_list DOT
  ;
statement_list:
  statement+
  ;
statement:
  if_statement
  | ...   //other statements
  ;
if_statement:
  IF condition THEN? statement_list
  (ELSE statement_list)?
  END_IF?
  ;
```

This grammar turn out to be slow for the style of code like the sample above. When debugging I found the parser is busy predicting inside if_statement. This is expected as there are ambiguities in the grammar. For the sample code, "IF condition-2 ..." can be recognized as either a child or brother of "IF condition-1 ...", because there can be an omitted "END-IF" right after S1. The inner most "IF condition-n" can have up to n choices. Similarly, every the END-IF before the DOT have alternatives over the "IF" they pair with if their total number is not n.

I tried to cut off alternatives by adding semantic predicates, like below:

```
statement_list:
  statement+  {_input.LA(1)==END_IF || _input.LA(1)==ELSE || _input.LA(1)==DOT}?
  ;  
if_statement:
  IF condition THEN? statement_list
   ( {_input.LA(1)!=ELSE}? | ELSE statement_list)
   ( {_input.LA(1)!=END-IF}? | END_IF) 
   ;
```

This reduced parse time of large programs by 2/3, but does not reduce it to be linear time, as deep prediction over if_statement and statement_list is  still observed. A closer look into antlr 4 runtime seems to show that semantic predicates are not used at all during prediction.

Does anyone know of a trick to make this "optional END-IF" unambiguous, or make it predict fast?

Actually there is also ambiguity for the statements before "ELSE", just like those before END-IF.

Note: Paring the sample with 30 levels of nested ELSE-IF uses 3 seconds on my machine. And I'm facing large programs that have many occurrence of such deep nesting and uses more than 10 minutes to parse. One of them even goes stack overflow when predicting.

Another note: I'm using antlr 4.2.

Comment: You certainly don't need semantic predicates. You just need to fix your grammar. I was involved with an *O(n)* recursive descent parser for Cobol-85 nearly 30 years ago. It can be done. Can't remember the details, but the biggest problem by far was not END-IF but abbreviated combined conditions. There's a [Cobol-85 grammar contributed to JavaCC](https://java.net/downloads/javacc/contrib/grammars/cobol.jj) that might repay close study.

Comment: You might try using [this release](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.tunnelvisionlabs%22%20AND%20v%3A%224.5%22) of ANTLR 4. It contains a number of optimizations not found in the reference release, many of which are centered around dealing with the right edge of rules like you've shown.

Comment: Remember the full-stop/period/dot is going to terminate *all* outstanding scopes, not just in IF. I don't think you are correct about what you seem to think the impact of the "omitted" END-IF is.

Comment: This also looks relevant: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/42 .

Comment: (At) EJP Yes, we met with problems around abbreviated combined conditions, but have solved it by modifying our grammar. @SamHarwell Thank you very much. Is this release of ANTLR 4.5 the version you mentioned before as an "optimized fork"?  Thank (At) rici too for the issue 42 descriptions. I wonder if the option s11 is available in 4.5.  Thanks to all.

Comment: @Sam Harwell Thank you and would you please answer briefly the questions in my last comment?

Comment: @BillWoodger is correct, the full-stop terminates ALL outstanding scope. If you have a triple nested IF inside a PERFROM VARYING and use a full stop, it will also close the PERFORM. In my experience, scope terminator don't seem change the performance of the code. maybe the compile time, but even then the difference is negligible.